# Unity Framework: How to Instantiate two classes from the same Interface?

Tags: inversion-of-control, unity-container

I have one interface with 2 classes implementing it, I need to load each class but unity has:

m_unityContainer.Resolve() // Where  is the interface IGeneric

my config looks like:

```
      <type type="IGeneric" mapTo="ClassA">
      </type>
      <type type="IGeneric" mapTo="ClassB">
      </type>
```

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: and I need to instantiate both classes at the same time

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a generic interface as follow:

```
public interface IGeneric{}

public interface IGeneric<T> : IGeneric{}
```

Then have a **type safe** resolution of the the interface:

```
container.RegisterType<IGeneric<ClassA>, ClassA>();
container.RegisterType<IGeneric<ClassB>, ClassB>();

ClassA classA = container.Resolve<IGeneric<ClassA>>();
ClassB classB = container.Resolve<IGeneric<ClassB>>();
```

Some interesting things start happening when you go down this road...

Comment: Something like this in config: <typeAlias alias="IGeneric`ClassA" type="MyNamespace.IGeneric`1[[MyNamespace.ClassA, AssemblyName]], AssemblyName" /> <type type="IGeneric`ClassA" mapTo="MyNamespace.ClassA, AssemblyName">

Answer (score 1):

This will give you all the registered classes that implement IGeneric.

```
IEnumerable<IGeneric> objects = container.ResolveAll<IGeneric>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution, a name property has to be used in each entry:

and the code will look like
 obj= container.ResolveAll("ClassA");

Answer (score 0):

Schalk - looks good. What would be the notation for specifying that in the Unity.config?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly different way.  I am using Unity.2.1.505.2 (just in case that makes a difference).

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration"/>
  </configSections>


      <unity>
        <container>
          <register type="IVehicle" mapTo="Car" name="myCarKey" />
          <register type="IVehicle" mapTo="Truck" name="myTruckKey" />
        </container>
      </unity>
```

Here is the DotNet code.

```
        UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

        UnityConfigurationSection section = (UnityConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity");
        section.Configure(container);


IVehicle v1 = container.Resolve<IVehicle>("myCarKey"); 

IVehicle v2 = container.Resolve<IVehicle>("myTruckKey");
```

See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664762(v=pandp.50).aspx